# Is it possible to hide content of a div behind a transparent one?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to erase the contents of a div behind another transparent div. Is it possible to do so, or does the div covering up another div have to be solid?
I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to explain what I want to do. 
Here is my code, if that helps.

CSS:

```
#div1 { 
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25em
}
#div2 {
  border: 1 px solid;
}
body {
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div2">
 Lorem ipsum
</div>

<div id="div1">
 <ul>
  <li> Aaaa </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want all of the elements in div2 (including the border) covered by div1 to be deleted, so that just the background shows.

Comment: use `visibility: hidden`, or `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just adjust the CSS to hide the div in question?

```
#div2 { 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

For more information please see [this MDN article on the `visibility` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `display: none` for your div?

Like:

```
.examplediv {
  display: none
}
```